# Dell PowerEdge 2850 with Gigabit NIC dual card

Tags: networking, performance, network-adapter

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2850 and I just recently upgraded my speed from my supplier to 300Mbps, when I run speedtest from my desktop computer I can achieve 306 download speeds and roughly the same or higher upload speeds. Yet, when I run speedtest on my server it gets to 306 dl but only 4.06 upload. What would cause this extreme difference? I have looked at all the settings in the router and can't see anything that would throttle it down.
The server is connected directly to the modem/router so no switch in between.

Comment: There are a bunch of possible causes. Have you tried connecting the server to another LAN port? Have you tried another network cable? Have you checked the connection between server and laptop (I recommend ```iperf```)? Are there lost packages when you ping the router? ... when you ping a remote server? What does ```mtr``` tell you about the connection?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I appreciate it... Changing the port has no effect, there is no connection to my laptop, the server is connected directly to the Modem/Router. No packets are lost when I ping outside IP address. I will have to do some switching around to report on the cable. Thanks again.